# Overwrite Mage_Core_Model_Resource in Magento

Tags: magento

does anybody know how to overwrite `Mage_Core_Model_Resource` located in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php`

Copying to `local/Mage/Core/Model/Ressource.php` seems not to be the perfect idea ;-)

thx for any help

Answer (score 2):

So I would suggest that rewriting `Mage_Core_Model_Resource` is not a good idea. This file is not often called itself but is mostly a parent class. I would suggest finding the case that you need a rewrite and rewriting the child classes instead.

These should be possible to rewrite with a simply module and config.xml rewrite but without know what exactly you need I can only recommend not rewriting `Mage_Core_Model_Resource` as a local file.

Comment: ive implemented a multiple slave setup for magento, overwriting the core function getConnection in Mage_Core_Model_Resource. Actually i've done this for testing in the core file.